# Spring @Resource Expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: java, spring, resources

I'm trying to run a web app and I'm having some issues. Basically I have a controller and a process and they both share a queue.

The controller manages the files that are uploaded to the server and it puts them in the queue. In the other side, the process takes the files in the queue and uses them for other things.

I've defined the queue as a LinkedBlockingQueue and the annotation @Resource on both of them, but when I run the app, the following exception appears:

```
Error creating bean with name 'csvQueueConsumerBean': Injection of resource 
dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue] found for 
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this 
dependency.
```

The code of both clases is the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class FileUploadControllerW {

@Resource
protected LinkedBlockingQueue<QueueObject> csvQueue;

...
}

@Component
public class CsvQueueConsumerBean{

@Resource
protected LinkedBlockingQueue<QueueObject> csvQueue;

...
}
```

Just for the record, both classes are not on the same package.

Comment: `LinkedBlockingQueue` bean does not exist in the Spring context that is why. You will have to initialise it the context!

Comment: where have to defined the queue? can you post that code

Comment: @theo, thanks for the answer. Could you tell me how can I do that? I'm still a noob with al this spring stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because `Spring` context cannot wire the `Bean` called

```
csvQueueConsumerBean
```

You will need to initialize its `LinkedBlockingQueue` dependency in the `Spring` config file like this:

```
@Bean
public LinkedBlockingQueue<QueueObject> linkedBlockingQueue(){
    LinkedBlockingQueue<QueueObject> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<QueueObject>();
    // do what you need here...
    return blockingQueue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.